# How to concatenate a wildcard with a filepath in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

In my script I'm trying to just get a count of files in a folder that matches a specified wildcard pattern. I'm trying to simplify parameters but I'm having issue.

Variables:

```
srcDir=I:\Script Testing  
srcPattern=file_*.json  
srcPath="$srcDir"/$srcPattern
```

I'm using quotes around $srcDir in the srcPath parameter because there is a space in the file path. Is there a better way to handle this?

Now if I do

```
fileCount=$(find "$srcDir"/$srcPattern -type f | wc -l);
```

fileCount is resolved to 3 which is correct.

However if I do

```
find $srcPath -type f | wc -l
```

It returns "No such file or directory".

I tried some more basic commands such as

```
echo "$srcDir"/$srcPattern
```

and it returned a list of all the files that matched that wildcard pattern.

However, doing

```
echo $srcPath
```

returns "No such file or directory".

Why is this? How do I resolve?

Relevant Portion of Script:
I've updated my script since posting to instead create an array of the files found instead of doing wc -l but my question doesn't change.

```
srcPattern=$1;
srcDir=$2;
        
srcPath="$srcDir"/$srcPattern;
            
fileList=($(find "$srcDir"/$srcPattern -type f -printf '%f\n'));
fileCount=${#fileList[@]};
        
if [ $fileCount -lt 2 ]; 
then
    echo "No merging needed as less than 2 data files were found"
    echo "Exiting..."
    exit 0;
else
    merge;
fi
```

Comment: the code you provide is not the code you are using. for example `srcDir=I:\Script Testing` would probably give an error message. please include the exact commands and the exact (complete) error messages they produce. Doing so is likely to make it obvious what is happening. (eg. the `find` error is lkely to include the precise path that it can't find)

Comment: Hi it is now added

Comment: You need `srcDir` quoted and `srcPattern` unquoted; you can't do that when they're both part of the same variable.

Comment: Think about `find "$srcDir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "$srcPattern"`, which is better practice anyhow.

Comment: Note too that `array=( $(somecommand) )` is unfixably buggy and should never be used. See [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) and [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29).

Comment: More appropriate (assuming a recent enough bash) would be `readarray -d '' fileList < <(find "$srcDir" -name "$srcPattern" -printf '%f\0')`, or if you need compatibility with bash 3.x, `fileList=( ); while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do fileList+=( "$file" ); done < <(find "$srcDir" -name "$srcPattern" -printf '%f\0')` -- that works with all possible filenames, including names with spaces, newlines, etc.

Comment: (I should have said, "_to rely on shell globs_, you need `srcDir` quoted and `srcPattern` unquoted"; as the above commands demonstrate, when you're letting `find` do the pattern matching instead of having the shell do it, then both expansions should be quoted).

Comment: You could also just do `fileList=( "$srcDir"/$srcPattern )` and directly store the glob _results_ in a variable instead of ever storing a glob _expression_ in a variable in the first place. Why invoke `find` in the first place?

Comment: Please get in the habit of only posting code that has already been cleaned up per testing at https://shellcheck.net . Good luck.

Comment: When I paste your code into `bash`, `srcDir=I:\Script Testing` gives me - not surprisingly - _bash: Testing: command not found_. Note that a backslash is a character with special meaning of bash. It does not make sense to use it in your way.